# Toshiba Satellite L655 Fan Not Running

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature, toshiba-laptop

A friend of mine has a Toshiba Satellite L655 laptop with an Intel Pentium processor.  After about an hour of use, or when a particularly resource-intensive program is being used, the machine will shut down abruptly as if the system overheats.  Opening the Toshiba PC Health Monitor reveals that the CPU fan is not running when the processor's temperature is above 50%.  I know that this is not normal for Toshiba laptops, as my own Satellite P755 (Intel i7-2670QM) reports that the fan is running at about 80% when the temperature is above 50%.

This leads me to believe that the CPU fan is either disabled or dysfunctional.  Does anybody know if it is possible for the fan to be disabled, and if so how to re-enable it?  Could a BIOS update resolve the problem?  (BIOS is currently v1.40, newest version is 3.60)  Or will the fan need to be replaced entirely?

Comment: Seriously doubt there would be a function to disable the fan. That would be asking for trouble. This is likely a case where the fan has simply failed. Have you verified there isn't blockage or dirt built up to prevent it from operating?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the BIOS configuration can cause such issue. Hence please open BIOS settings and navigate to  "Hardware Monitor" option  then make sure fan is enabled. Also try updating the BIOS with default settings or most recent good configuration, then check the status.